# Drupal 7 - Moderators list on the forum page

Tags: drupal-7

I'm looking for a solution to a simple (or simple at first sight) problem - I'm using Enterprise Forum with the Forum Access module on Drupal 7 and I need to make a list of moderators under each forum on the forum list page.

One similar solution can be found here: http://drupal.org/node/319232 but wherever I look, I only find solutions for Drupal 6. Is there a way to write a similar piece of code that would work in Drupal 7?

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use organic groups for this .
The process goes like this:-
1. Create a forum content type and make this a group type.
2. Add content , discussions making it group content type.
3. Finally use Views module and Panels to align the layout of things.
4. Use Og group members node and attach to the view.

Og group members is used to see who have joined your forum plus one more thing it has group membership that shows the moderator of the page/forum/group depending on the content type used.

You can also follow Organic Groups tutorial from ModulesUnraveled.com
They have a complete tutorial for Organic Groups very neatly explained.

Hope this might solve your issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with the Views module. http://drupal.org/project/views

Comment: Ok, tried it, figured it won't work the way I want it to. I like the forum list page as it is now - with all the notices about new posts, statistics and tools (like "mark all as read" or "view unanswered posts"). I need it to look and function exactly like it does now (well, it's pretty much the default advanced forum main page) with the only exception which is the moderators list under each forum, so the code that I can add to the template would be much appreciated.

But anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Are there defined regions?  Can't you just create a block and have it display on the main forum page?